# Multivariate polynomials with given real zeros

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, real-algebraic-geometry

Given natural numbers $N$ and $n$, I am looking for a family $P_{Nn}$ of polynomials in $n$ variables
with the following properties:

(i) Every polynomial in $P_{Nn}$ is determined by the function values at $v_{Nn}$ expliclitly known points.

(ii) For every set $S$ of $N$ real $n$-dimensional vectors, one can construct explicitly a polynomial in $P_{Nn}$ which has the vectors in $S$ as isolated zeros, and no other real zeros?

For $n=1$, the set of all polynomials of degreen $N$ with highest coefficent $1$ works; as polynomial we can take the product of the $x-s$ with $s\in S$. For $N=1$ we can take the sum of squares of $x_i-s_i$, where $s\in S$.

But what happens for $N,n>1$? I'd like to have a family such that I can retrieve $S$ from a reasonably small number (preferably $v_{Nn}=O(Nn)$) of function values by a reasonably simple algorithm.

That something better than the trivial family, which takes the product of $N$ terms of the solution for $N=1$, can work can be seen by considering the case $n=2$, where one can encode the vectors in $S$ by $N$ complex numbers, use the recipe for $n=1$, and regard the complex polynomial as a bivariate polynomial in its real and imaginary part.

Given the comment by @Gro-Tsen below, it would be sufficent for me to have a system $F(x)=0$ of $O(n)$ polynomial equations whose common zero set is $S$, if this system can be algorithmically determined uniquely from values of $F$ at a set $X$ of $O(Nn)$ appropriate points, where $X$ is independent of $S$.

Comment: Do you want just any family with this property, or do you have more requirements? The obvious way is to take $\prod_{s\in S}\sum_{i<n}(x_i-s_i)^2$, which has degree $2N$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek See the amendment of my question

Comment: From the algebraic-geometrical point of view, the zero set of a single (nonzero) multivariate polynomial is a hypersurface. So you want to construct a hypersurface with only $N$ real points. I don't have a proof at hand but I think it has to be singular at these points. This *suggests* that you can't do much better than Emil Jeřábek offered. Unlike in the $n=1$ case where you can actually get only $N$ geometric (i.e., complex) points.

Comment: Concerning the last paragraph: in this way you get *two* multivariate polynomials, *both* of which have to vanish. Now, if you combine them to a single polynomial by taking the sum of squares of the real and imaginary part, you get exactly $\prod_s(x-\operatorname{Re}s)^2+(y-\operatorname{Im}s)^2$ again (this is simple algebra). Hence you do not get anything better this way, actually.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: How many function values of your solution are needed to reconstruct $S$? It seems to be exponentially many....

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Please look at the final paragraph of my question, which I added after pondering your remark.